# Ошибка cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, android

Всем привет! Собираю кастомную прошивку, портирую функции в неё, у меня есть вопрос по данному коду:

```
package com.octogen.settings.fragments;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.UserInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.UserHandle;
import android.os.UserManager;
import android.support.v7.preference.ListPreference;
import android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.preference.Preference;
import android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceCategory;
import android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen;
import android.support.v7.preference.Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener;
import android.support.v14.preference.SwitchPreference;
import android.provider.Settings;
import com.android.settings.R;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import com.android.internal.logging.nano.MetricsProto;
import com.android.internal.util.abc.AbcUtils;
import com.android.settings.SettingsPreferenceFragment;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import android.provider.SearchIndexableResource;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import com.android.settings.search.BaseSearchIndexProvider;
import com.android.settings.search.Indexable;
import com.octogen.settings.preferences.SecureSettingSwitchPreference;


public class PowerMenuSettings extends SettingsPreferenceFragment
                implements Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener, Indexable {

    private static final String TAG = "PowerMenuSettings";
    private static final String TORCH_POWER_BUTTON_GESTURE = "torch_power_button_gesture";

    private ListPreference mPowerMenuAnimations;
    private SecureSettingSwitchPreference mAdvancedReboot;
    private ListPreference mTorchPowerButton;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.octogen_settings_power);

        final ContentResolver resolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
        final PreferenceScreen prefScreen = getPreferenceScreen();

        mPowerMenuAnimations = (ListPreference) findPreference(POWER_MENU_ANIMATIONS);
        mPowerMenuAnimations.setValue(String.valueOf(Settings.System.getInt(
                getContentResolver(), Settings.System.POWER_MENU_ANIMATIONS, 0)));
        mPowerMenuAnimations.setSummary(mPowerMenuAnimations.getEntry());
        mPowerMenuAnimations.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);

        mAdvancedReboot = (SecureSettingSwitchPreference)
                findPreference(Settings.Secure.ADVANCED_REBOOT);
        mAdvancedReboot.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);

        if (!AbcUtils.deviceHasFlashlight(getContext())) {
            Preference toRemove = prefScreen.findPreference(TORCH_POWER_BUTTON_GESTURE);
            if (toRemove != null) {
                prefScreen.removePreference(toRemove);
            }
        } else {
            mTorchPowerButton = (ListPreference) findPreference(TORCH_POWER_BUTTON_GESTURE);
            int mTorchPowerButtonValue = Settings.Secure.getInt(resolver,
                    Settings.Secure.TORCH_POWER_BUTTON_GESTURE, 0);
            mTorchPowerButton.setValue(Integer.toString(mTorchPowerButtonValue));
            mTorchPowerButton.setSummary(mTorchPowerButton.getEntry());
            mTorchPowerButton.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceTreeClick(Preference preference) {
        return super.onPreferenceTreeClick(preference);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {

        ContentResolver resolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();

        boolean result = false;
        if (preference instanceof ListPreference) {
            if (preference == mPowerMenuAnimations) {
               Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.POWER_MENU_ANIMATIONS,
                       Integer.valueOf((String) newValue));
               mPowerMenuAnimations.setValue(String.valueOf(newValue));
               mPowerMenuAnimations.setSummary(mPowerMenuAnimations.getEntry());
               return true;
            }
        } else if (preference instanceof SecureSettingSwitchPreference) {
            if (preference == mAdvancedReboot) {
               boolean value = (Boolean) newValue;
               Settings.Secure.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ADVANCED_REBOOT,
                       value ? 1:0);
               Settings.Secure.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.GLOBAL_ACTION_DNAA,
                       value ? 1:0);
            }
            return true;
        }

        if (preference == mTorchPowerButton) {
            int mTorchPowerButtonValue = Integer.valueOf((String) newValue);
            int index = mTorchPowerButton.findIndexOfValue((String) newValue);
            mTorchPowerButton.setSummary(
                    mTorchPowerButton.getEntries()[index]);
            Settings.Secure.putInt(resolver, Settings.Secure.TORCH_POWER_BUTTON_GESTURE,
                    mTorchPowerButtonValue);
            if (mTorchPowerButtonValue == 1) {
                //if doubletap for torch is enabled, switch off double tap for camera
                Settings.Secure.putInt(resolver, Settings.Secure.CAMERA_DOUBLE_TAP_POWER_GESTURE_DISABLED,
                        1);
            }
            return true;
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static final Indexable.SearchIndexProvider SEARCH_INDEX_DATA_PROVIDER = new BaseSearchIndexProvider() {

        @Override
        public List<SearchIndexableResource> getXmlResourcesToIndex(Context context,
                boolean enabled) {
            ArrayList<SearchIndexableResource> result =
                    new ArrayList<SearchIndexableResource>();

            SearchIndexableResource sir = new SearchIndexableResource(context);
            sir.xmlResId = R.xml.octogen_settings_power;
            result.add(sir);

            return result;
        }

        public List<String> getNonIndexableKeys(Context context) {
            ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
            return result;
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int getMetricsCategory() {
        return MetricsProto.MetricsEvent.OCTOGEN_SETTINGS;
    }

}
```

Не собирается с ошибкой:

```
PowerMenuSettings.java:70.64: POWER_MENU_ANIMATIONS cannot be resolved to a variable
```

Comment: Попробуй заменить `POWER_MENU_ANIMATIONS` на `Settings.System.POWER_MENU_ANIMATIONS` в 70 строчке

Comment: Спасибо, но дело было не в этом =) я добавил ответ на свой вопрос)

Comment: Да, я видел, и даже плюсанул его)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Упс, вопрос снят, это не добавил:

```
private static final String POWER_MENU_ANIMATIONS = "power_menu_animations";
```